# TFS Find by Status Display files checked out to doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

In vs2013/tfs using Find by Status works for "Display all checked out" but not when I type in a user for "Display files checked out to:".

I type the user name exactly (including case) as it appears in the returned list for the all search but the user specific search always returns: No items found.

Comment: Have you tried typing the internal name (not the person's full name) i.e. include the user's domain? E.g. COMPANY/johns instead of John Smith?

Comment: Doh!  Yes, if I use DOMAIN\username instead of just username, it works!  It would be nice if the results screen displayed the username the same way you have to enter it to get the search to work.  It doesn't; it only displays the username (no domain).   Anyway, thanks! I can't mark this as answered because you only commented.  If you put your comment as an answer, I will mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried typing the internal name (not the person's full name) i.e. include the user's domain? E.g. COMPANY/johns instead of John Smith?